# How to access a 3g IP camera from the outside?

Tags: proxy, router, nat, 3g, camera

I had no idea 3g devices could not be directly reachable from the outside. So I bought everything (sim card + contract + 3g router) hoping I could hook up my IP camera to the router and the router to the internet through 3g. Nothing is accessible from the public IP (i can't reach the camera, not even the router management site).

Is there any creative way around this? Like setting up a server in the middle where the camera should send the images and I could see them through that server? Something like a reverse proxy maybe?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the camera, some have a mini server built in for serving up a live feed.  Possibly just need to forward the ports.  Do you have a model number for the hotspot and the camera?

Yea, the manuals for the camera and the 3g router should be enough to do this.  You should go ahead and setup a DynDNS account so you can get a dynamic dns address.  One downside with the 3g router is that you might lose the IP address if it loses connection and reconnects.  Using DynDNS you can have a name of your choosing point to your IP address and if you forward the port to the camera it should take you to the camera management page.

Comment: It's this Wanscam (http://bit.ly/TqhDX7) not exactly sure about its model number.
I've been messing around with the config trying to figure it out, all I saw a bit interesting was the possibility to upload jpeg images to a FTP server (like every 30 seconds)...I'd be happy with even that. But for some reason when I set up the FTP login the camera config page freezes and nothing happens...! :'(
About forwarding the ports, nothing can't enter from the outside at least directly. It's frustrating